# setting up multiple wordpress sites on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: lamp, wordpress, vps

Just a simple question but what I am wanting to do is setup multiple WordPress sites on a single Ubuntu 14.04 VPS LAMP stack and my question is regarding the folder structure for the content of the files in /var/www. In this tutorial by Digital Ocean, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-multiple-wordpress-sites-on-a-single-ubuntu-vps (based on a Ubuntu 12.04) the files are placed in /var/www/firstsite/ , /var/www/secondsite/ etc... However, I have noticed that in another digital ocean tutorial for setting up one WordPress site in Ubuntu 14.04 https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-14-04 , the documents are placed in /var/www/html/. so my question is this, should my folder on Ubuntu 14.04 for multiple WordPress site look like this /var/www/html/firstsite/ , /var/www/html/secondsite/ or should it just look like this: /var/www/firstsite/ , /var/www/secondsite/ etc... as per Justin's tutorial for Ubuntu 12.04?

Any help much appreciated, Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder in which your file needs to be placed depends on your current DocumetRoot of your Apache configuration.

try this command on terminal

```
cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*.conf
```

You get something like this

[image]

Now check for your DocumentRoot

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response. When I read what you suggested I got the same as you posted in the image above. So does that mean that my folder structure should be /var/www/html/firstsite/ , /var/www/html/secondsite/ ?

Comment: Exactly..  you have to put your firstsite and secondsite to /var/www/html/

Comment: If u find this is the correct answer.. please click the gray tick mark on the left side, for helping others too